# FirstOrDefault() throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following line of code:

```
var y = userRep.All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
```

userRep is a repository class, the All method is defined as

```
public IQueryable<User> All
{
    get { return _context.Users; }
}
```

userName is passed into the function, using the debugger I can verify that it has a value.  Whenever I run that line of code I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

If I hard code the condition to `x.UserName == "abc"` it works fine, but I'm not sure why it keeps thinking userName is null when the debugger shows it has a value in there.

Comment: can you post the rest of the code where `username` is defined?  is the value of `username` exactly the same as the value you hard coded?  does calling `FirstOrDefault` with that hard coded username return a `User` object? is the null reference exception referring to your `y` variable or is that thrown from within your call to `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: `x.UserName == "abc"` returns value or it is null?

Comment: can you show us how did you initialize `_context` and when ?

Comment: x.userName == "abc" returns null, so after that line y = null, which is fine as that username doesn't exist in the db.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @Slauma the 1st thing on the trace is Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices.SetDbParameterValue(DbParameter parameter, TypeUsage parameterType, Object value) +86 so it looks like something with Glimpse, i will try to remove it and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

your this line of code is right:

```
var y = userRep.All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
```

if suppose for a second userName is null, even in that case it will not throw exception, but if the query returned null means no record found, then `y` will be null and it will through exception when you will access it or iterate over  it.

It will throw exception if you have not instantiated `userRep`.

Do like this, before querying the db, assuing your dbcontext class name `MyDbContext`

```
var userRep = new MyDbContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having more details, and taking for granted that any of the previous proposed answers  didn't solve your issue, I can think of another possible reason: "userName" variable (or other outer variable not shown on your examples) is getting "captured" and, eventually, something is changing its value. For example

```
var y = userRep.All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
...
userName = null;
...
foreach(var x in y){...}
```

Read more about this in here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, it had to do with Glimpse and Entity Framework, I found this link with details: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/766 I had to downgrade Entity Framework to 6.0.2 and it works now.